# in kotlin data class, @field:NotBlank not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

We are currently using jdk 14, spring boot 2.2.8.RELEASE, and Kotlin 1.5.31. the below class used to error on blank first or name.

now that we are trying to update to spring boot 2.5.4 it's no longer throwing the error in our automated test case.

```
data class ChangeInformationRequest(
    @field:NotBlank var firstName: String,
    @field:NotBlank var lastName: String,
    @field:Valid var address: Address?
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the Spring Boot validation starter is no longer included in web starters (which I am guessing you are using) from Spring Boot 2.3 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters). This means that `spring-boot-starter-validation` is no longer a transitive dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. As a consequence you have to actually add the dependency yourself to your `pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I suggest you go through all the relevant Spring Boot release notes so that you can learn upfront which are the major changes that might affect your code:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes